# Android market: developer name doesn't appear under the app

Tags: google-play

I've published my first app 3 days ago (as you see it's my first app, please go easy on me :) ), I don't understand why there is no developer name under the application. I've checked the user profile and there is a developer name but I don't see it in the android market. What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it took some time to appear (2 day) but it did so problem solved.